# Unchecked assignment on creating an array of lists

Tags: java

I'm creating an array of lists of strings like this:

```java
List<String>[] newList = new List[arrayLength];
```

It works but gives the following warning:

> Unchecked assignment: 'java.util.List[]' to 'java.util.List<java.lang.String>[]'

Comment: Read about Generics in Java. Your list is of a raw type because it is missing type information preventing your compiler from checking them.

Comment: I don't put this in as an answer because those are Java basics. You obviously have to put in the type for the definition as well: `new List<String>[arrayLength]`

Comment: Arrays and generics don't work well together. Why should you use an array of lists anyway? Just use a `List<List<String>>`.

Comment: @Smutje nope, if I do that i get the error **Generic array creation** instead of just a warning

Comment: @MCEmperor i wanted to use an array because i already know how many elements i'm trying to manage so i don't need a flexible arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this without getting a warning, because arrays and generics don't work well together.

Why should you use an array of lists anyway? Just use a `List<List<String>>`.

You say you "don't need" a flexible arraylist, but who said you should use an `ArrayList`? `List` is an interface, and some implementations don't allow resizing. For instance, `Arrays::asList` returns a fixed-sized list.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify your List type (here I use String) in order to solve the warning.

I break it down in steps to simplify understanding:

```
    List<List> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> innerList = new ArrayList<>();
    innerList.add("first value");
    innerList.add("second value");
    myList.add(innerList);
```

If your fixed array is mandatory you can use:

```
List<String>[] myList = new List[2];
myList[0] = Arrays.asList("Test 1", "Test 2");
myList[1] = Arrays.asList("Test 3", "Test 4");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myList));
```

**Output - No warnings received**

```
[[Test 1, Test 2], [Test 3, Test 4]]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I'm trying to create an array of lists, not a list of arrays

Comment: So the solution is to manage the list in another list instead of an array? Is there no way to do it with an array?

Comment: Hi @krrbrr !
Please check my last edit, I hope it works for you now.